# Force Eclipse to automatically import a class with multiple options

Tags: java, eclipse, templates, import

If a class is used in a Java project in Eclipse, and it's not imported already, and there is only one class with that name, Eclipse will automatically import it.

If there are two or more classes with the same simple name, Eclipse will ask the user to select the desired one. I would like to avoid having to select one and instead prefer having a default class imported.

For example, I commonly use `List` and `ArrayList`. And each time I use them in a new class, I have to select `java.util.ArrayList` and `java.util.List` from the suggestions of Eclipse, because there is another class with the name `List` (`java.awt.List`).

Is there some way to set `java.util.List` and `java.util.ArrayList` as a default import if `List` and `ArrayList` is used?

---

For now, I created an Eclipse template that triggers on the word `List`. Are there any other ideas or improvements?

```
${:import(java.util.List,java.util.ArrayList)}
List<> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: After typing List<> list = new ArrayList<>(); ... can't you just do ctrl+shift+o and let eclipse import them all at once?

Comment: @CoolBeans Eclipse will prompt you to choose between various lists e.g. `java.util.List` or `java.awt.List`. That's what the OP wants to avoid.

Comment: I'd be content if the first option was always the obvious (most often used) one, but even that isn't guaranteed unfortunately.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you don't use AWT in the project you can limit your accessible API like I mentioned in my blog: http://blog.firdau.si/2010/07/07/limit-your-access-to-java-api-for-more-productivity/

Works like a charm for me!

Comment: @nanda The link to your blog is down. Could you please post the details of the answer here? thanks

Comment: you know if I can limit this for my whole Eclipse installation or workspace? I've dozens of Projects in eclipse and I don't want to configure this for each one.

Comment: @philnate try Type filters

Answer (score 18):

You can also use the "Type Filters" from the Eclipse Preferences menu. This allows you to 'forbid' java.awt.* for all of your projects rather than just one.

Java -> Appearance -> Type Filters (or search for "Type Filters")

Answer (score 3):

Either you can add "Access Rules" on your project's properties or (this seems even better if you for example won't need java.awt.List at all) Go to your workspace's Preferences,

Java->Appearance->Type Filters (or search for "Type Filters")

And add your classes and packages to be ignored here