# Auto import for more classes

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I configured eclipse to auto import all needed classes on save. But in the case where there are multiple classes with the same name like `java.util.List` and `java.awt.List` eclipse doesn't import any of the possibilities and leaves it to the user. In most cases I want to use the same class (in our example it's `java.util.List`). Is it possible to define some default class such that eclipse knows which class I mean when I type `List`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to force eclipse to auto import a class when more then one option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870750/how-to-force-eclipse-to-auto-import-a-class-when-more-then-one-option)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a way to define a default import for some name like `List`,
but you can tell Eclipse to never automatically import some specific classes like `java.awt.List`. It will then automatically import `java.util.List` because this is the only remaining option.

This feature is called "Type Filters" and available under Preferences -> Java -> Appearance -> Type Filters. Just add `java.awt.List` to it.